# Favorites in jobs doesn't work right

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Go to jobs.  Click on a favorite.  Notice the number of favorites on the right side.  Click that same star yet again to unfavorite it.  The count should be minus one..instead it is now plus 2.  Keep doing this over and over the count just keeps increasing.

Also when you favorite your first job the right hand label says "You have no favorite jobs":

[image]

Comment: We have changes in the pipe that are currently undergoing QA, they'll *probably* be released next week.

Comment: This was completed a long time ago